# Facebook API block user search

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there any way in the facebook js api to access the list that apears when you make a search in the "block users" bar.

I need to get the same list it generates when navigating to that search rather than the general search. If this isn't available in the API is it possible to crawl through this information somehow?

Below are 2 screenshots showing how to navigate to the search :

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So to be clear i just want the list of names generated in the second screenshot, i don't need any ids or anything like that

Comment: The link that is being posted to by facebook that is returning the html for the list i need is https://www.facebook.com/ajax/browser/dialog/block_users/?q=james&update_privacy_lite=1

Answer (score 1):

**No**. You cannot access the block list of a user because of the privacy limits.